# How can I animate the drawing of a complex line shape in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-2d

So say I wanted to animate drawing this shape:

[image]

Animate it something like the disney logo which seems to "write" the letters.

Ideally, I'd also like to have control over how fast it was drawn (maybe just easing), how would I go about getting that done? Specifically imagine if that link had a line of varying widths.

Not too familiar with drawing things in objective-c so perhaps someone can help point me in the right direction in terms of strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `CAShapeLayer` and set that shape as its path. Use a `CABasicAnimation` or a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to animate its `strokeEnd` property.

Comment: How would I "set that shape as it's path"? Assuming I have that shape as .png asset.

Comment: There is no easy way to turn a png into a path that you can animate.

Comment: So I would have to first figure out how to turn a png into a path...?

Comment: Is the image known at compile time or provided at runtime?

Comment: It is known at compile time

Comment: Then use a vector graphics editor like Inkscape or Illustrator to trace the shape as a path that you can export as SVG. Then you can look at the SVG and convert it to code to build a UIBezierPath. Or you maybe can use PaintCode to create the code.

Comment: Hmm I suppose that is something I'll have to look into then. Can I also vary line thickness this way?

Comment: No, you won't be able to vary the line thickness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127678/discussion-between-user1416564-and-rob-mayoff).